# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'release'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I come from RDBMS background and just starting on python. below is a simple code i written to invoke my web cam via python

```
import cv2

vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
 while vid == True:
     print("Connected....");
if cv2.waitKey(0) : break

cv2.release();
```

but i am getting error

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'release'
```

while executing it. I am running this code using python3.5 and on linux 14.04 platform. I can see cv2 package installed via help("modules") list and it gets imported as well without error . however i dont see it in the interpreter list of pycharm. please help.

Comment: it seems like i had issues with openCV and python3.5 which are still unknown to me. i switched back to python2.7 and used the blog at [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/) to install opencv and it worked without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

`cv2.release()` does not exist. I think what you are trying to do is `vid.release()`

`cv2` is the opencv module and `vid` is the `VideoCapture` object. which is the one that you have to do the release.

## UPDATE:

The code you have has several mistakes. Before I only addressed the one you asked, but lets go through all of them.

First one, the indentation is wrong, I guess maybe it is from copying the code.

Second one

```
while vid == True:
```

This is not the correct way to do it. You can use the `vid.isOpened()` function to see if it opened/connected to the webcam.

Third one, you do not need to use `;` after the instructions.

Fourth one, this one is not an error, but something that is not necessary

```
if cv2.waitKey(0) : break
```

the if is not necessary, waitKey will return the key pressed as an ascii character, if you use a number other than 0 it will return 0 if no key was pressed. But with 0 it will wait for a key to be pressed "blocking" the current thread (in case you have more than one). However, it will not wait unless that you have a `imshow` window opened.

Now, the complete code with those changes that I wrote and that checks if the script can connect to a camera will be

```
import cv2

vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if vid.isOpened():
  print ("Connected....")
else:
  print ("Not Connected....")

vid.release()
```

In a similar fashion you can display the video until a key is pressed:

```
import cv2

vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if vid.isOpened():
  print ("Connected....")
  while True:
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    if ret:
      cv2.imshow("image", frame)
    else:
      print ("Error aqcuiring the frame")
      break
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF:
      break
else:
  print ("Not Connected....")

vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If something is not clear, feel free to ask  :)

Comment: aah...my bad... it did stop that error but still my cam is not invoked. can you please suggest anything i am missing.

Comment: @PawanRawat sure, I wrote an update of the answer. I think I cover all the possible problems and gave you some simple examples to test :)

Comment: Thanks api55 for your help... really appreciate you explaining to that level. its my first script actually...now i executed the code you provided however i i get the message "not connected .." ...is there still anything i am missing ?

Comment: @PawanRawat no problem, If you like the answer consider upvoting, or accepting it so other people know that is a working solution. For this other problem, it could be several things. You can try `vid.open()` if `vid.isOpened` returns false and test again. If it still fails, [OpenCV tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) recommend to test it first with another app, like cheese in linux.(`sudo apt-get install cheese`) and then run it

Answer (score 0):

import cv2
import numpy

img = cv2.imread("lena.jpg", 1)
cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.waitKeyEx(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Comment: try using cv2.waitkeyEx(0)

Comment: In order to build a better answer, I suggest you to incorporate all info in the answer (from comments) and, most importantly, to add some explanation on how it works and why is solves OP's issue.